# Browser (chrome, firefox) download static file slow with nginx, not with apache2

Tags: nginx, apache2, firefox, chrome

I'm struggling with the fact that when having Nginx serving a 1.8 Gb file, when I put the URL in either Chrome or Firefox the download goes with 5 Mb/s, when I do it with wget or curl, same url, same client pc, the download goes with (my max.) 25 Mb/s. With Apache, serving the same file, it goes 25Mb/s with both browsers and curl/wget. My question is: why?

It's a pretty default config, I put either the X-Sendfile (apache2) or X-Accel-Redirect (Nginx) in the header, I've tried several configs with nginx, I can slow it down with limit_rate but not up. This is the location part of my default link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
location files/ {
        internal;
        alias /var/www/html/;
        #directio 100m;
        output_buffers 2 512k;
        limit_rate 30000k;
        sendfile_max_chunk 0;

}
```

I turned on directio, left out or left in the other options, turned sendfile on/off, no difference.

Comment: With text based browser (lynx) it goes max speed 25 mb/s as well...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Apache2 automatically fills out headers for size and file type, while Nginx, when none specified, uses text/html for type, and no size.

So, adding:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-length: {$result[0]->size}");
```

Speeded the downloads up a factor ~ 5, working with my max. bandwidth.